# can someone explain me the bool part in this function

Tags: python, python-3.x

This is a code in python, I understand what the function is aiming for but I don't understand the sample and the condition part, can someone explain it to me?

```
def calculate_stdev(self, sample=True):

    """Function to calculate the standard deviation of the data set.
    
    Args: 
        sample (bool): whether the data represents a sample or population
    
    Returns: 
        float: standard deviation of the data set

    """

    if sample:
        n = len(self.data) - 1
    else:
        n = len(self.data)

    mean = self.mean

    sigma = 0

    for d in self.data:
        sigma += (d - mean) ** 2
    
    sigma = math.sqrt(sigma / n)

    self.stdev = sigma
    
    return self.stdev
```

Comment: `sample (bool): whether the data represents a sample or population`. That's just 2 ways of calculating stdev... You can google it and find some formulas, then the code will make sense. Right now, I don't see how this question is even about code

Comment: See [Differences Between Population and Sample Standard Deviations](https://www.thoughtco.com/population-vs-sample-standard-deviations-3126372#:~:text=The%20population%20standard%20deviation%20is,the%20individuals%20in%20a%20population.)

Answer (score 0):

This is a question about math, not a question about computing.

Sample standard deviation is a different formula from Population standard deviation.

If you Google with "Bessel's correction" then you can find all about it.

Answer (score 0):

The N-1 is Bessel's correction. If you are working with a sample of the data instead of the entire data, you use that correction. You can read more here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel%27s_correction